# Solr: Want query suggestions

Tags: solr

In my solr documents there is a field group.

How can i write a query which will give me documents in this order

1. group:img (this group total documents should be 5).
2. group:news(this group total documents should be 1).
3. group:wiki(this group total documents should be 1).
4. group:blog(this group total documents should be 1).
5. group:book(this group total documents should be 1).
6. group:""(this group total documents should be 6).

Is it possible or i have to write separate query for each.

Comment: Can you try something like http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=id,name&q=solr&group=true&group.field=group&group.limit=10

Comment: Yes, i can do that. But why?

Comment: Check if you get the data grouped by group field...the limit for every grouing field cant be achieved at solr end...you neeed to apply some login at your end..

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a **ordered** query with different subqueries, each one with a specific **limit**, together with **where** clauses.

I don't think that is possible to do in SOLR.

Take a look at [Filter Queries (fq)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) and see how far you can go with that.